# Update browser every 2 hour (if there is connection)?

Tags: php, flash, connection

I'm experimenting with a digital signage solution that just view a flash-player on repeat in Firefox (R-kiosk installed)

Now I run a  that makes the player update every 2 hour (I use remote update)

The problem is that sometimes the router loses its connection. The browser only says "Your internetconnection is lost..." or something.. 
Is there any possibility to:
**check if there's internet connection (every 2 hour)**
and if it is, update. Else don't.
I use php.

Thanks!

Comment: Who updates what? You want to refresh a browser page every two hours, if possible, correct?

Comment: Simply make JavaScript or Flash connect to the server every 2 hour.

Comment: **SomeKittens:** I simply use:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="7200">

**twall** Correct. I want to refresh Firefox, if there's internet connection

**Anne** I don't know how to do that I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 0):

Use an ajax request in the background to keep connection alive or test:

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("page not found");
        }
    }
});
```

You can use this portion of code to supplement your own ajax status detector. Just find out which code you get when connection is lost and build from there...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/